# How i can solve shell command error ?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

i'm using shell coding to change a file code by "sed" commnand.

```
sed -i -- 's/0 * * * * /home/flash/eAn/etl/repcompre.sh start/#0 * * * * /home/fla/eAn/etl/repcompr.sh start/g' '/tmp/.tab.tmp'
```

its not working i have this error :

```
    sed: -e expression #1, char 19: unknown option to `s'
```

Thanks

Comment: You are using slash in `s///`, you need to screen slashes: `\/`. The same is with `*`.

Comment: use a different delimiter when you have slashes in your string e.g. sed 's@/opt/omni/lbin@/opt/tools/bin@g' path.txt

Comment: can you give me example ?

Comment: Because you only want to place a character at the beginning of the line you could place what you have found into the replacement `sed -e 's@\(.*/home/flash/eAn/etl/repcompre.sh\]@#\1@'`

Answer (score 0):

From `info sed`, section "The 's' command":

> The syntax of the 's' command is 's/REGEXP/REPLACEMENT/FLAGS'.
>
> […]
>
> The '/' characters may be uniformly replaced by any other single
>   character within any given 's' command.  The '/' character (or whatever
>   other character is used in its stead) can appear in the REGEXP or
>   REPLACEMENT only if it is preceded by a '\' character

In other words, whenever your `REGEXP` or `REPLACEMENT` contains slashes you have to *either*

- replace the slashes between and around `REGEXP` and `REPLACEMENT` with another character like `@` or `%` or
- prefix each slash in `REGEXP` and `REPLACEMENT` with a backslash (`\`) character.